# Using Beans in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I'm coding a program in java that take a few information from a graph (X axis and Y axis), and then I need to take this information and pass to a JSP page.

this is the java

```
package view;

public class Axis{
       double[] axisX;
       double[] axisY;
       int test;

       public Axis(){
       }

       public void setAxisX(double[] axisX){
           this.axisX = axisX;
       }

       public void setAxisY(double[] axisY){
           this.axisY = axisY;
       }

       public double[] getAxisX(){
           return axisX;
       }

       public double[] getAxisY(){
           return axisY;
       }
}
```

Then in the JSP is this what I have to do?

```
<jsp:useBean id="view" class="view.Axis" scope="session"/>
Test: <%= view.getAxisX() %>
```

Comment: You should start learning `JSTL`. JSP scriplets should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are basically trying to do is use Standard Actions :

```
<jsp:useBean id="view" class="view.Axis" scope="session"/>
<br> X :<jsp:getProperty name="view" property="axisX" />
<br> Y :<jsp:getProperty name="view" property="axisY" />
```

You can use [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html)/[JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) for this instead of Standard Actions.

Also read ,

[How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)